# how can i find the structure of a downloaded c++ software source code

Tags: c++, treeview, doxygen

I have got a c++ software from git.There is no documentation of the code.To understand the code, I need a way to figure out the classes & which functions call the other, preferably in the form of a tree.

I tried with doxygen, but i got only class description. I didnt get function hierarchy. Is it possible to get function hierarchy details using doxygen?

Comment: Are you saying, that you are unable to find a download link for doxygen? Or are you looking for a manual, of how to do it with doxygen?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse (CDT - which is the C++ version) and Visual studio IDEs support building call hierarchies and caller hierarchies for any method you choose.

You can start from the main() and then dive in...

I suppose other IDEs such as CLion also support this.

I am presonally not familiar with a tool that will graph out all the code at once and in any case I think the output of such a full graph would be unreadable.

I suggest you choose an IDE and go from main() and build "call hierarchies" from the methods. Another good method would be to run it with debug and trace through it, then you can choose how deep you can go into the call hierarchies of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proper IDE like Microsoft Visual Studio. Here requested [link](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#gitrepos) for doxygen. You can clone it from git